# How do I prevent scrolling the window/body "through" a modal div?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

Here is a simplified version of my layout:

```
<body>
    [... a bunch of content ...]
    <div id="modal-overlay">
    </div>
</body>
```

`body` contains enough content that the entire page scrolls.

`#modal-overlay` is styled like this:

```
#modal-overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

In response to a user action, I'll display the `#modal-overlay` by setting `display: block;`

The `#modal-overlay` then fills the entire viewport.

Here's the trouble...

***SOMETIMES,*** when you swipe vertically on the the `#modal-overlay` - its content scrolls as it should.

However, ***SOMETIMES,*** the `body` scrolls instead, and the content in `#modal-overlay` doesn't scroll at all. It's as if I'm scrolling `body` *through* the `#modal-overlay`, which is exactly what I **don't want.**

In fact - it seems totally random whether `#modal-overlay` or `body` scrolls in response to the swipe gesture.

I've read about a few hacks (e.g., applying `overflow:hidden` to the `body` but I don't want to do that, since it loses the correct scroll position, and causes other problems as well.) I also would like to have a solution that works with any number of nested layers. I'm really trying to prevent scrolling *through* the uppermost layer, not fiddling with the underlying layers.

This is particularly problematic on iOS, since scrolling the `body` reduces the height the browser chrome, which expands the viewport, which messes with the layout of the `#modal-overlay`, since it's sized to fill the viewport. Aaargh.

Thanks in advance for any advice or guidance!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried to achieve this on ios, but you can at least give a try using [slimscroll jquery plugin](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll) if you are dealing with multiple layers and prevent scrolling of other layers.
Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the link. However, I'm hoping to find a pure JS solution. Ideally, I'm really just hoping to understand how iOS decides whether to scroll the <div> or the window/body, so that I can control that behavior.

Comment: The scrolling basically depends on, the block your pointer is in, if that block is reaches to end of scrolling the it's parent block is selected for scrolling and so on, till the body of the document..

Comment: you can achieve this using javascript only but then if you have take into consideration like mousewheel events behavior in different browsers, things you have to are first check mouseenter event then mousewheel event then set scrollTop by calculating scrollheight and clientheight.

Answer (score 1):

`Body` should be `overflow-hidden` and 
add dynamically `position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%` CSS properties to other content wrapper (content container inside the body) in the body when modal open.

When open the Modal

```
  <style>
   .modal-open {
     overflow: hidden;
   }

   .modal-open .container {
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
   }
  </style>

<body class="modal-open">

  <section class="container">
     Site content will be here
  </section>

  <div class="modal">
     Modal content will be here
  </div>

</body>
```

Add this "`modal-open`" class dynamically when open the modal and remove it when it close.

Comment: this works great! Thank you! Quick question... I've read elsewhere that setting `overflow:hidden;` on the `body` will cause it to lose the current scroll position (which would be a bad side-effect). However, when I implemented your solution - that did not happen. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: Normally It can't happen due to 'overflow: hidden' property.

Sometimes, if someone using anchor tag with # for modal open, then it's scroll to the page top when closing the modal. 

<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#">Modal open</a>

That's mean it's happen due to '#'.

Comment: Sorry - I spoke to soon. This *almost* works. On iOS - you have that rubber-band effect that allows you to *scroll past* the top or bottom, only to have it snap back into place. And you can still do this *through* the modal, so sometimes the modal won't scroll when it should. Also - setting `overflow:hidden` ***does*** set the scroll position to 0 on the body, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `modal-overlay` covers the body 100%, I believe adding `position:fixed` to `body` when you display the `#modal-overlay` will fix your issue.